# Error in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor.es5.js during build of angular application

Tags: angular, npm, rich-text-editor, syncfusion

We are using the following versions in my package.json "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^17.3.28": , "typescript": "^3.1.3", "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",

When we are trying to build the project with npm run build:ssr ,it is displaying the following error.

ERROR in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor.es5.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at getJSDocTags (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13197:22)
    at getFirstJSDocTag (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13205:24)
    at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13154:19)
    at checkParenthesizedExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45628:56)
    at checkExpressionWorker (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45676:28)
    at checkExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45155:29)
    at checkBinaryExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45147:20)
    at checkExpressionWorker (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45702:28)
    at checkExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45609:42)
    at checkExpressionCached (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45457:38)
    at getTypeOfExpression (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45577:28)
    at checkDeclarationInitializer (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45469:24)
    at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30738:28)
    at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30961:24)
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31062:28)
    at getTypeOfSymbol (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31242:24)
    at checkVariableLikeDeclaration (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:47828:41)
    at checkVariableDeclaration (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:47891:20)
    at checkSourceElement (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:49864:28)
    at Object.forEach (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1792:30)
    at checkVariableStatement (/media/devteam/New Volume/GIT_LFS/trd_11_2019_code/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:47901:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-io-example@1.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod --aot --buildOptimizer && ng run angular.io-example:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-io-example@1.0.0 build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have validated the reported issue and we were unable to reproduce it. For your convenience we have attached a demo sample. Kindly check and get back to us, if the reported issue is still persisted in the attached demo. Also make sure that you have used latest version of **"@angular-devkit/build-angular"** dependency in your application.

Demo sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/syncfusion-angular-app752756918

It will be more helpful to provide better solution at earlier, if you are provide more information to get your issue reproducing scenario.

Feel free to contact us, if you need further assistance on this.

Regards,

Narayanasamy P.